# Finding a sequence of continuous functions $f_n$ such that $g(x)=\sup\{f_n(x):n \in N\}$ is not continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

> Find a sequence of continuous functions $f_n: [0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$ such that the function $g:[0,1] \mapsto [0,1]$ given by $$g(x) = \sup\{f_n(x):n \in N\}$$
>   is not continuous.

That is the problem, so here it goes:
I want to use the definition of piecewise linear, following the theorem that tells about the continuous piecewise linear function which uses some $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ to prove it.

I'm thinking that I can do the above and just create some general sequence that fits the Interval $[0,1]$.

I also believed that I can use the stair function to also complete the same type of deal. I have a problem figuring out the significance of the statement $$g(x) = \sup\{f_n(x):n \in N\}$$Any help, suggestions, edits or criticisms would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Construct an increasing sequence of continuous $f_n$'s which converge to some discontinuous $f$. Since the sequence is monotone, your $g$ equals the $f$. Note that the convergence cannot be uniform...

Answer (score 2):

You can think about $f_{n} \left( x \right) = \mathrm{min}\left(nx,1\right)$. The limit $f$ coincides with the sup, and it is discountinuous since $f\left( 0\right) = 0$ and otherwise $f\left(x\right)=1$.